# Sorted-List alphabetical order using compareTo()

Tags: java, linked-list, compareto, sortedlist

Can someone help me with my sorted linked list. it's supposed to print things in alphabetical order. I have 2 problems.

1.When I add first when numNodes = 1, the first one auto disappears(in this case Elaine disappears).
2.Subsequently, the item that is supposed to be the last remains the first while the rest are arranged nicely.

```
101 public void addOrdered(E item) {
102         ListNode<E> newNode = new ListNode<E> (item, null);
103         if(numNodes == 0)   {
104             this.addFirst(item);
105             System.out.println(numNodes);
106             return;
107         }
108         else if(numNodes == 1)  {
109             ListNode<E> curr = head;
110             // if alphabetically in front, add in front
111             if((newNode.getElement()).compareTo(curr.getElement())<0)   {
112                 System.out.println("ADD IN FRONT");
113                 this.addFirst(item);
114                 return;
115             }   
116             // if alphabetically behind, add behind
117             else    {
118                 System.out.println("ADD IN BEHIND");
119                 curr.setNext(newNode);
120             }   
121         }   
122         else    { //find position to add in between
123             ListNode<E> curr = head.getNext(), prev = head;
124             while((curr != null) && ((newNode.getElement()).compareTo(curr.getElement())>0 ))   {
125                 prev = curr;
126                 curr = curr.getNext();
127             }   
128             newNode.setNext(curr);
129             prev.setNext(newNode);
130         }   
131         numNodes++;
132             System.out.println(numNodes);
133     }       
134 }
```

My input is

```
Elaine Diana Avery Candy Bubble
```

My output is

```
1
[Elaine]
ADD IN FRONT
[Diana]
3
[Diana, Avery]
4
[Diana, Avery, Candy]
5
[Diana, Avery, Bubble, Candy]
List: 
[Diana, Avery, Bubble, Candy]
```

Comment: do the comparison with node==null insted of node==0. And what is numnodes pointing to?